# How to model dependent events occurring a constant rate?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I have a series of events with a certain magnitude of each event. Each dot on my graph is an event and its y-axis number is it's magnitude.

I would say that events with more than about 300 in magnitude occur throughout the data at a reasonably constant rate and that they are roughly evenly spread out. I want to be able to predict when one of these >300 events is going to occur.

I hypothesise from my knowledge of what this data represents, that these event magnitudes are dependent on each other, in the sense that the after a string of smaller events (<300), it makes it more likely that the next event will be positive (>300)

I want to be able to predict the rough probability of a >300 event after a string of lets say, 3-4 (or x), <300 events. I understand the Binomial distribution makes the assumption that events are independent, so I cannot use that.

I was hoping someone could shed some light on how to approach this problem.

Kind Regards

[image]

Comment: You might start by looking at serial correlation (with various lags) to see if observations are random or independent. It is inevitable in a sequence like this that there will be a number of small events before each large one. In order to gain traction, you need to formulate a specific predictive pattern from this and other historical sequences and then see how it performs on future data. Wishing you success with this. Along with geologists, I have looked at sequences of California quakes, trying to find a predictive pattern, but with no success.

Comment: Doing a quick count (which might be wrong), you seem to have $169$ events of the $100-300$ type, and $26$ events of the $300+$ type including the last one.  If these were randomly distributed  (e.g. geometrically with $p=\frac2{15}$), I might expect about $13.3$ big events to be preceded by $0-4$ small events while you have $11$; about $6.5$ big events preceded by $5-9$ small events while you have $7$, and about  $6.2$ big events preceded by $10+$ small events where you have $8$.  Those are not big differences

Comment: Thanks very much to both of you. The data does seem to fit a geometric distribution. I am adjusting my "percentage confidence of a big event" based upon the geometric CDF and it works well. Thanks for your well wishes - I hope your research goes well. @BruceET. Henry if you want to present your comment as an answer, ill accept it.